# Rshiny - need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I cant figure out what im doing wrong because as i searched about that error mostly its because of NA values but i checked my dataset in rscript for NA values and it was okey no missing values at all.

Dataset -
[image]
I put my data on this link in csv file https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UWWwkhQo9IBf-CYp5JNGPZLa8j1atRSQ?usp=sharing
My UI

```
library(shiny)

bank <- read.csv("F:/Downloads/SKola/BP/Shinyapp/BankMarketing/data.csv", header = TRUE , sep = ';')

  ui = tagList(
    
    navbarPage(
       theme = "cerulean", 
      "BankMarketing",
      tabPanel("Zakladne Grafy",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file", "File input:"),
                 
                 selectInput("atribut1", "Vyber atribut", colnames(bank), selected = "y"),
                 selectInput("atribut2", "Vyber druhy atribut", colnames(bank)),
                 radioButtons("button","Vyberte farbu grafu",choices = c("red", "blue")),
                 
                 tags$h5("Default actionButton:"),
                 actionButton("action", "Show"),
                 
                 
               ),
               mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
                 
                
      ),
      tabPanel("Navbar 2", "This panel is intentionally left blank"),
      tabPanel("Navbar 3", "This panel is intentionally left blank")
    )
  )
```

My server

```
library(shiny)
bank <- read.csv("F:/Downloads/SKola/BP/Shinyapp/BankMarketing/data.csv", header = TRUE , sep = ';')
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server = function(input, output) {
  output$tab <- renderDataTable(bank)
  
  output$plot = renderPlot({
    x = bank[ ,input$atribut2]
    y = bank[ ,input$atribut1]
    (plot(x,y, col=input$button))
  })
}
```

Comment: `selectInput("atribut1", "Vyber atribut", colnames(bank), selected = "y")` Do you have a column named "y" ?

Comment: The error suggests an issue with your data, but you haven't shared your data.  So it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: yes i do have Y

Comment: ill pin here my data also sorry